# What happens to cursors in android when shifting between activities?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have an activity where I have one list with database content. When I click something on the list it starts a child activity where it shows the text of that element.

When this was using only one table I could come back to the parent without a problem. Now I want to pick on a menu between 2 different tables to fill the ListView. It works fine and picks/fills the ListView with the correct table, but when I go to the new activity and try to come back to the main activity it crashes.

The only difference in the code is one if/else, and it loads correctly when you go there the first time, it only has the problem coming back to the activity.

Maybe this is a newbee question, but what can be the problem? I already spend hours on this without getting to a solution. I assume it can be something with the cursors as that is the part I understand less about.

The logcat error is:
 **java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.aeroex.aeroexlib/eu.aeroex.aeroexlib.DBDisplay}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference**

Again, this only happens when coming back from the child activity, no problems when creating it, and the problem does not happen if I take the "if" and use only one table option.

```
if (pick.equals("0"))
    CustomListViewValuesArr = myDbHelper.getPart66(cursor);

    else
        CustomListViewValuesArr = myDbHelper.getPart147(cursor);
```

I seem to have identified the problem. When I declare

```
String pick = pickMenu.getStringExtra("position");
```

To know which menu was picked, it does not work properly when you come from a child activity. How could I still pass that info?

Comment: Please post the relevant code and logcat error message.

Comment: It has a complex structure behind that to put here. I assume it can be something with the recalling of the activity has it picks and creates it correctly. I just don't know where to look as android does the recreating automatically

Comment: Please post the full log. From what I can see, you are getting an NPE in `DBDisplay`. Additional information will be in LogCat.

Comment: better use fragments

Comment: I think the problem is after all with the if statement itself. I declared String pick = pickMenu.getStringExtra("position");      If I try to change it for something like 3 == 7 it starts working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The question should be "what happens to an originating activity when shifting between it and other activities".

The answer: it might be destoryed and be recreated if the child-activity is left and the programm flow returns to the originating activity.

destoryed and recreated means all member variables of the activity (including your cursor member) loose their content (or will have a null value)

For details see https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: I seem to have identified the problem. When I declare

String pick = pickMenu.getStringExtra("position");
To know which menu was picked, it does not work properly when you come from a child activity. How could I still pass that info? Or save it when I go to a child activity